# sql use different columns for same query (directed graph as undirected )

Tags: sql, graph

Suppose I have a table of relationships like in a directed graph. For some pairs of ids there are both 1->2 and 2->1 relations, for others there are not. Some nodes are only present in one column.

```
a    b
1    2
2    1
1    3
4    1
5    2
```

Now I want to work with it as undirected graph. For example, grouping, filtering using both columns present. For example filter node 5 and count neighbors of the rest

```
node neighbor_count
  1    3
  2    1
  3    1
  4    1
```

Is it possible to compose queries in such a way that first column `a` is used and then column `b` is used in the same manner?

I know it is achievable by doubling the table:

```
select a,count(distinct(b)) 
from 
    (select * from grap 
    union all
    select b as a, a as b from grap) 
where (not a in (5,6,7)) and (not b in (5,6,7)) 
group by a;
```

However, the real tables are quite large (10^9 - 1^10 of pairs). Would `union` require additional disk usage? A single scan through the base is already quite slow for me. Are there better ways to do this?

(Currently database is sqlite, but the less platform specific the answer the better)

Answer (score 0):

The `union all` is generated only for the duration of the query.  Does it use more disk space?  Not permanently.

If the processing of the query requires saving the data out to disk, then it will use more temporary storage for intermediate results.

I would suggests, though, that if you want an undirected graph with this representation, then add in the addition pairs that are not already in the table.  This *will* use more disk space.  But you won't have to play games with queries.